# Copy native NuGet-packaged DLL to build output

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget, nuget-package, csproj

I have a .NET Standard 2.0 C# project Foo that produces a NuGet package with the following directory structure:

```
build/
    x64/
        FooNative.dll
lib/
    netstandard2.0/
        FooManaged.dll
        Foo.dll
foo.nuspec
```

The project relies on a managed DLL (FooManaged.dll), which wraps a native DLL (FooNative.dll).

I then add a reference to this Foo.nupkg package from another C# project Bar.csproj: all works fine, except the build output of Bar contains only the managed DLL, not the native one. I have tried many ways to alter the Foo.csproj, so that the package will ensure the DLL is copied to the output folder at during build time of Bar. Below are the relevant parts of the  Foo.csproj:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>Foo</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Foo</AssemblyName>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
    <version>0.0.0</version>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64'">
    <OutputPath>bin\x64\Release\</OutputPath>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <LangVersion>6</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- bundle wrapped .dlls into the nupkg -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="ThirdParty/FooManaged.dll">
      <Pack>true</Pack>
      <PackagePath>lib/netstandard2.0</PackagePath>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="ThirdParty/FooNative.dll">
      <Pack>true</Pack>
      <PackagePath>build/x64</PackagePath>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Foo">
      <HintPath>ThirdParty\FooManaged.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ContentWithTargetPath Include="ThirdParty\FooNative.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <TargetPath>FooNative.dll</TargetPath>
    </ContentWithTargetPath>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Here, the `CopyToOutputDirectory` tag seems not to have the desired effect.

How can I ensure the DLL is copied to the build output directory as required?

Note: we are using `dotnet pack` to package Foo.

Comment: Go to Solution Explorer and delete FooNative.dll.  Then add by using Add Existing and browser to folder where dll is located.  The dll will automatically be added to the proper bin folder (like debug or release).  Are you trying to make sure when you publish that file is copied?

Comment: Thanks, I just tried but it doesn't seem to help. In answer to your question, I am trying to ensure that when I build a project which depends on this package, the necessary native DLL is copied to the build output folder.

Comment: See the green tip : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-change-the-build-output-directory?view=vs-2022

Comment: Good suggestion, but I think the build configuration is not the issue here: the managed DLL ends up in the correct location. The package itself is only built release.

Comment: Use Solution Explorer and right click the bad dll.  Under Properties there is a copy option.

Comment: I've written some draft docs that I haven't found/made the time to finish and get merged. Anyway the topic of the docs are exactly what you're trying to achieve: https://github.com/NuGet/docs.microsoft.com-nuget/pull/3092

Comment: Thanks @zivkan I will have a read and try again. This area is under-documented I believe so this is an appreciated addition.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working eventually: all that was required was for me to add the following ItemGroup to the original .csproj:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="ThirdParty/FooNative.dll" Link="runtimes/win-x64/native/FooNative.dll">
    <PackagePath>runtimes/win-x64/native</PackagePath>
  </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```